# Excluding rows based on column

Tags: sql

I am trying to exclude rows where a value exists in another column of other row.

```
select * from TABLE1

ID1 ID2 VALUE
1   1   HIGH
2   2   MEDIUM
3   3   LOW
4   4   HIGH
5   4   HIGH
6   6   MEDIUM
```

All the data is coming from the same table what I want is to exclude ID1 = 4 because the value 4 exists in column ID2 in row 5. The final desired result is as follows:

```
ID1 ID2 VALUE
1   1   HIGH
2   2   MEDIUM
3   3   LOW
6   6   MEDIUM
```

I tried using a simple query such as:

```
Select * from TABLE1 Where ID1 = ID2
```

But this will wrongly also include row 4 as below since I need to exclude it because the value exists in another row but in ID2 column:

```
ID1 ID2 VALUE
1   1   HIGH
2   2   MEDIUM
3   3   LOW
4   4   HIGH
6   6   MEDIUM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add, this will exclude the records where you see more than 1 ids.

```
and id2 not in (Select id2 from table1 group by id2 having count(*) > 1)
```

Similarly add for id1 with OR

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logic in the query below.

```
select * from t T1
Where 2 > (Select count(1) from t T2 where T2.id2 = T1.id2);
```

Comment: thanks for this. To explain my logic, I want to exclude rows four and five because they are actually a pair. Thats why ID1 in row four is equal to ID2 in row five. Since they are a pair, I want to exclude both of them.

Comment: @rain123 - Got it. Thanks for the clarification! Please See my edit above.